# What does '0xDEAD' mean in the following code?

Tags: enums, magic-numbers, sentinel

There is an enum structure,but I don't understand the meaning of '0xDEAD - 2' in this enum.

```
enum TerminatedTypes {
    _not_terminated = 0xDEAD - 2,
    _thread_exiting,                            
    _thread_terminated,                          
    _vm_exited                                   
};
```

From the code above,What kind of  benefit can I get?

The code above is in 'hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/thread.hpp' in openjdk8.

I am studying source code of jdk,please help me.

Comment: It's just a sentinel value selected because it's hex representation looks cool.

Comment: That a hex literal... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: It's an example of a [*magic number*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29). Another is `0xCAFEBABE`.

Comment: _thread_terminated means dead and _not_terminated is dead - 2. I guess it's a programmer's trick to match word dead to a hexdecimal number 0xDEAD. maybe more meaningful and readable!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a hex literal, being used as an eyecatcher (useful in debuggers) so that the `_thread_terminated` value will be `0xDEAD` ("terminated thread" equals "dead").

There's a host of hex literals people use for things like that, such as `DEADBEEF` from [the Jargon file](http://catb.org/jargon/html/D/DEADBEEF.html), and so on.