# What does it mean when I get a SIGSEGV from 0xdead4321 in libc?

Tags: android, linux, memory-address, segmentation-fault, libc

I found this line in my ADB log exactly 2 seconds before my app crashed:

[image: The following line in an ADB log: 01-20 13:23:02.520 A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdead4321 (code=1), thread 7324 (Thread-522)]

Obviously, the memory address `0xdead4321` is faked on-purpose. **Why was this fake address used, what does it mean, and how can I avoid this fatal signal?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196013/why-application-is-dying-randomly

Perhaps this can help?

Comment: @bluerojo That may answer my third question, and possibly the second, but definitely not the first.

Comment: It is a HEX literal. used as an eyecatcher

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735847/what-does-0xdead-mean-in-the-following-code

Comment: @bluerojo but why not actually list the address of the problem?